# How do I add a signature to a pdf file on Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: 22.04, pdf

I have tried with Libre Draw and Document viewer, but did not find a signature option.

Am I missing it in these applications, or should I try another program?

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you mean a printed signature (ie not a digital one) -

You can edit pdf files using Scribus (available in the software centre). There are other programs that allow pdf editing but it's the only one I could get to work for me and it certainly lets you add a signature.

If you open the file in Scribus, then copy your signature picture from wherever you store it (I keep mine in a LibreOffice Draw file), you can paste that in to the pdf - it'll appear in a separate box that you can drag to wherever you want it in the document.

To save the pdf - you don't choose `Save` or `Save as` - instead select `File` - `Export` - `Save as pdf`.

Comment: Scribus just ruined the formatting of the other fields I already filled in.

Comment: @Scorb - that’s a shame; I’ve not had that happen with my pdfs. Sorry I don’t have any other ideas.